# How to 'add' QuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-filters

I have written the below code.

```
for number in numbers:
    booking_list = Booking.objects.filter(rooms=number)
```

Here, `numbers` is a list of numbers.

The problem with this code is that `booking_list` will only contain the QuerySet of the last number as the previous QuerySets will be overwritten but I want `booking_list` to contain all the QuerySets. Moreover, I want the QuerySets to be unique. In other words I want a `union` of the QuerySets.

The reason as to why the QuerySet may have repeated vaues is because `rooms` is a list of numbers.

Comment: Show your models?

Comment: @Sumithran The actual code is quite complicated. I have simplified and asked the question but if you want here is the link to my GitHub repo (https://github.com/AnshulGupta22/room_slot_booking)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup with [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) so:

```py
booking_list = Booking.objects.filter(rooms__in=[i for i in numbers]).distinct("rooms")
```

Comment: Are you sure I can use `in`. `rooms` is a CharField. It can have values like [4, 21, 62, 50, 2, 12]. If the value of `number` is `50`. Then your query will translate to `select * from Booking where [4, 21, 62, 50, 2, 12] IN 50`. I do not think it is correct.

Comment: @AnshulGupta Well share your model in the question by editing.

Comment: @AnshulGupta Do you mean it is like `ArrayField` of Integers?

Comment: I am using SQLite. It does not have `ArrayField`. I have added models.py and views.py file. I hope it helps.